# Connecting sattelite receiver HDMI with windows 8 computer

Tags: windows-8, connection, satellite

I have a satellite receiver with HDMI output can I connect this to a HDMI port on mt windows 8 computer and watch my channels on my screen. If so, do I need additional hardware/software?

Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 2):

You can hook up any HDMI output device (satellite receiver, cable, Xbox, etc) to your computer if you have a HDMI input device.  More than likely you do not, as they are not commonly installed on computers.  In order to do this, you will need a [HDMI video capture card](http://www.newegg.com/Product/ProductList.aspx?Description=hdmi%20capture%20card&Submit=ENE) or [TV tuner card](http://www.newegg.com/Video-Devices-TV-Tuners/SubCategory/ID-47).

In addition to that, HDMI ports are either in, or out, never both.  The HDMI port you see on your computer is most likely your video card's HDMI out, which connects to a monitor or TV.